# Alternatives to Altiris/Symantec SVS

Tags: windows, software-rec, 64-bit

I use an old copy of [Altiris SVS](http://lifehacker.com/162910/hack-attack-safely-install-software-in-a-virtual-layer) (link to lifehacker - Symantec gutted the old Altiris website) for testing applications - it lets me capture the changes one executable makes, or changes to a whole system into a bundle, and remove the whole bundle once I'm done. However Symantec bought over Altiris and apparently killed off the product, or merged it into some other bigger product.

I'd like the same fine grained control SVS had, something that just does this, and preferably free (for personal use) or not too expensive.

I'd like this to run on at least Windows XP 32 bit, but Windows 7 and 64 bit support would be nice too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently it got renamed as [Software Workspace Virtualisation](http://www.symantec.com/business/workspace-virtualization). It was almost impossible to find (which is why it took me this long to answer), and may need a  (free) account with symantec. When you install it, you can choose to get the installation key for personal use , or get the key from [the old altiris website](http://www.altiris.com/Download/svsPersonal.aspx) first, and use that.